# Loop with selenium and pandas doesn't work (python)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, selenium

I'm trying to scrape a website using selenium and pandas. I'm using a csv for urls (home.csv with 3 urls). The code is working fine but it takes only the last url from the csv and I can't the problem (it creates test_1.csv with data collected from last url only). What I want is to collect (append) all data from each url into a new csv (test_1) using pandas DataFrame. My code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import pandas as pd
import csv
import time

s=Service('/Users/christian/Desktop/Scrape/Jupiter/chromedriver')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s)

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
webdriver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, options=chrome_options)

with open('home.csv') as csvfile:
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    next(readCSV)
    
    for row in readCSV:
        url = row[1]
   
    
    with webdriver as driver:
        wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
        driver.get(url)

        location = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//div[1]/div[1]/h1').text
        tot_prop_rent = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//div[1]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]').text
        last_14_days = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//div[1]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]').text
        average = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//div[1]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]').text.split()[0]
        median = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//div[1]/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[2]').text.split()[0]

        
        data_list = []
        
        data = {
            'Location': location,
            'Total properties': tot_prop_rent, 
            'Properties listed in last 14 days': last_14_days, 
            'Average rent': average, 
            'Median rent': median
            }
        data.update()
        data_list.append(data)

        driver.quit()
        time.sleep(10)

        df = pd.DataFrame(data_list)
        df.to_csv('test_1.csv', index=False)
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Indent lines from `with webdriver as driver:` to `data_list.append(data)`, so it falls under the `for` loop.

Comment: Thanks Mark, done that but now it only takes data from the first url and shows an error:    MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=51270): Max retries exceeded with url: /session/f299d2b758888b0b37c7f3542dce21e2/url (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f8d00f2f580>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 61] Connection refused')).         Any thoughts?

Comment: You're reseting the empty list at each iteration. You should create the empty list `data_list` outside the `for` loop

Comment: Working now, thank you both